# Derived tensor product

Tags: math-mode, tensor

I tried to write derived tensor products using semantex (copied from p. 27 in the manual).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,semantex}

\NewSymbolClass\MyBinaryOperator[
    define keys={
        {Lder}{upper=L},
        {Rder}{upper=R},
    },
]
\NewObject\MyBinaryOperator\tensor{\otimes}[
    define keys={
        {der}{Lder},
    },
]
\NewObject\MyBinaryOperator\fibre{\times}[
    % Americans are free to call it \fiber instead
    define keys={
        {der}{Rder},
    },
]

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    A\tensor[R,der] B 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would like the L to appear on top of the tensor symbol instead of to the right. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Is my question unclear? I'm new to this site so just tell me if I can write it better. :)

Comment: Use `\overset{\tensor}{L}`.

Comment: @azetina Thanks for your answer! But is it possible to make it a key like above so I can still write \tensor[R,der]?

Comment: Yes. Use command `command=\overset{L}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a MWE using `semantex`. The idea is to use the `command` key and input the desired command. In this case, you want to over set the L on the symbol. Thus, using `command=\overset{L}` will suffice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,semantex}

\NewSymbolClass\MyBinaryOperator[
    define keys={
        {Lder}{command=\overset{L}},
        {Rder}{upper=R},
    },
]
\NewObject\MyBinaryOperator\tensor{\otimes}[
    define keys={
        {der}{Lder},
    },
]
\NewObject\MyBinaryOperator\fibre{\times}[
    % Americans are free to call it \fiber instead
    define keys={
        {der}{Rder},
    },
]

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    A\tensor[R,der] B 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I wanted! :)

Comment: Note that @egreg solution and Alan Xiang are also viable and robust.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to do it with `semantex`, but it's not difficult with other tools.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { cinque/tensor }
 {
  der .tl_set:N = \l__cinque_tensor_upper_tl,
  der .default:n = L,
  unknown .code:n = \tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l__cinque_tensor_subscript_tl { } { \l_keys_key_str },
 }
\tl_new:N \l__cinque_tensor_subscript_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\tensor}{O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { cinque/tensor } { #1 }
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__cinque_tensor_upper_tl
   { \otimes }
   { \overset{\l__cinque_tensor_upper_tl}{\otimes} }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__cinque_tensor_subscript_tl { \sb{\l__cinque_tensor_subscript_tl} }
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$A\otimes B$

$A\tensor B$

$A\tensor[R] B$

$A\tensor[der,R] B$

$A\tensor[R,der] B$

$A\tensor[\mathcal{X}] B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `\sb` mean?

Comment: @azetina It's an alias for `_`; needed because `_` doesn't mean “subscript” in the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn`

Comment: @egreg When I wrote `semantex`, I tried using the `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` trick, but ran into issues since some math did not come out as expected after being turned into a string and rescanned. This (and a few other things) prompted me to build my own, separate keyval system (using `\keyval_parse:NNn`). I never quite figured out the pattern of what code survived the string-ification and rescan. Maybe you can enlighten me?

Comment: @Gaussler I have no idea of what will turn out to be useful. I'd just do `\NewDocumentCommand{\dertensor}{o}{\overset{L}{\otimes}\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}}` which is simple and effective.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but it’s sometimes hard to properly control your notation from the preamble. Imagine you make a command `\stalk` for stalks of a sheaf at a point so that `\stalk{#1}{#2}` produces `#1_{#2}`. Applying it to `\mathcal{O}_{X}`, and you get a double subscript error. I prefer a keyval-based solution where I can write `\sheafF[\vX, stalk=\primep]` (with `\vX` meaning “variable *X*” and `\primep` being the prime ideal fraktured *p*) and make it stack the subscripts according to a preprogrammed procedure.

Comment: Here, `\sheafF` should have been `\sheafO` or `\sheafreg`.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_doc_tmpa_clist
\tl_new:N \l_doc_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_doc_tmpb_tl

\tl_new:N \g_doc_template_a_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g_doc_template_a_tl {
  \overset{\tiny L}{*1}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn {NnV}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\tensor}{O{}}{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \tl_set:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_tl {\otimes}
  
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_clist {
    \str_case:nn {##1}{
      {der} {
       \tl_set_eq:NN \l_doc_tmpb_tl \g_doc_template_a_tl
       \regex_replace_once:nnN {*1} {\u{\l_doc_tmpa_tl}} \l_doc_tmpb_tl
       \tl_set_eq:NN \l_doc_tmpa_tl \l_doc_tmpb_tl
      }
    }
  }
  
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_clist {
    \str_case:nn {##1}{
      {R} {
       \tl_set:No \l_doc_tmpa_tl {\l_doc_tmpa_tl \c_math_subscript_token {R}}
      }
    }
  }
  
  \mathbin{\tl_use:N \l_doc_tmpa_tl}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\par $a \tensor[R] b$
\par $a \tensor[R,der] b$
\par $a \tensor[der] b$
\end{document}
```