# Key values using l3keys (pencil symbol)

Tags: latex3, xparse, l3keys, l3draw

Consider the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l__pencil_dim
\fp_new:N \l__pencil_linethickness_fp

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pencil_diagram:n
 {
  \dim_set:Nn \l__pencil_dim { #1 }
  \draw_begin:
  \draw_transform_rotate:n { 110 } %rotation
  \draw_linewidth:n { \l__pencil_linethickness_fp }
  \draw_cap_round:
  \draw_join_round:
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.0\l__pencil_dim , 0.125\l__pencil_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.125\l__pencil_dim , 0.0\l__pencil_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.0\l__pencil_dim , 0.0\l__pencil_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.0\l__pencil_dim , 0.25\l__pencil_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.125\l__pencil_dim , 0.25\l__pencil_dim }
  \draw_path_close:
  \color_fill:n { black } %color
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill, stroke }
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 1.125\l__pencil_dim , 0.0\l__pencil_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.25\l__pencil_dim , 0.0\l__pencil_dim }
  \draw_path_curveto:nn
    { 1.35\l__pencil_dim , 0.125\l__pencil_dim } 
    { 1.25\l__pencil_dim , 0.25\l__pencil_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.125\l__pencil_dim , 0.25\l__pencil_dim }
  \draw_path_close:
  \color_fill:n { black } %color
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill, stroke }
  \draw_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\explpencil}{ O{1ex} }
 {
    \fp_set:Nn \l__pencil_linethickness_fp { 0.08ex }
    \pencil_diagram:n { #1 }
 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\explpencil[2ex] sample text
\end{document}
```

In @egreg [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570976/10898) he used `l3keys` values to define the inputs a user can have and notably the usage of `tl_if_empty:NTF`. I like the fact that the inputs are not mandatory and dependent on the user.

How can I create similar key values focusing on the colour (`\l__pencil_color`), dimension (`\l__pencil_dim`) and rotation (`\l__pencil_rotation`). The names in the parenthesis are just suggested names.

I am looking for possibilities like

- `\explpencil`,
- `\explpencil[2ex]`,
- `\explpencil[2ex,30]`,
- `\explpencil[red][2ex][30]`

preferably if the order of the input does not matter but could generate the expected results; say `\explpencil[red][2ex][30]=\explpencil[2ex][red][30]`.

Comment: I'd suggest to not use multiple optional arguments, but instead one in which you give a comma separated list. And while we could make guesses as to which value should belong to which variable (certainly possible), it might be a better idea to really choose `l3keys` and have an interface like `\explpencil[dim=2ex, color=red, rot=30]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One optional argument is good, two can be remembered; more than two always require to look at the manual for their relative order.

Using a key-value syntax is much better when there are many options to set.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% user interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\explpencil}{ O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \aze_pencil_diagram:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
 } 

% variables and variants
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \color_fill:n { V }

\dim_new:N \l__aze_pencil_size_dim
\fp_new:N \l__aze_pencil_linethickness_fp

\keys_define:nn { aze/pencil }
 {
  size  .dim_set:N = \l__aze_pencil_size_dim,
  color .tl_set:N  = \l__aze_pencil_color_tl,
  color .initial:n = black,
  angle .fp_set:N  = \l__aze_pencil_angle_fp,
  angle .initial:n = 110,
  thick .dim_set:N  = \l__aze_pencil_thick_dim,
 }

% internal implementation
\cs_new_protected:Nn \aze_pencil_diagram:n
 {
  \keys_set:nn { aze/pencil } { size=1ex, thick=0.08ex, #1 }
  \draw_begin:
  \draw_transform_rotate:n { \l__aze_pencil_angle_fp } % angle
  \draw_linewidth:n { \l__aze_pencil_thick_dim }
  \draw_cap_round:
  \draw_join_round:
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.000\l__aze_pencil_size_dim , 0.125\l__aze_pencil_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.125\l__aze_pencil_size_dim , 0.000\l__aze_pencil_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.000\l__aze_pencil_size_dim , 0.000\l__aze_pencil_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.000\l__aze_pencil_size_dim , 0.250\l__aze_pencil_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.125\l__aze_pencil_size_dim , 0.250\l__aze_pencil_size_dim }
  \draw_path_close:
  \color_fill:V \l__aze_pencil_color_tl %color
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill, stroke }
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 1.125\l__aze_pencil_size_dim , 0.0\l__aze_pencil_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.250\l__aze_pencil_size_dim , 0.0\l__aze_pencil_size_dim }
  \draw_path_curveto:nn
    { 1.35\l__aze_pencil_size_dim , 0.125\l__aze_pencil_size_dim } 
    { 1.25\l__aze_pencil_size_dim , 0.250\l__aze_pencil_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.125\l__aze_pencil_size_dim , 0.25\l__aze_pencil_size_dim }
  \draw_path_close:
  \color_fill:V \l__aze_pencil_color_tl %color
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill, stroke }
  \draw_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\explpencil{} sample text

\explpencil[size=2ex] sample text

\explpencil[size=1ex,color=red,angle=50,thick=0.01ex] sample text

\end{document}
```

The possible options are `size`, `color`, `angle` and `thick`. The last one is mostly irrelevant for black pencils, it becomes important for colored ones.

Why do `color` and `angle` have initial values while `size` and `thick` don't? Because we'd like tha `size` to be in terms of `ex`, so that the drawing adapts to the context. If we set `size` initially to `1ex`, this would be the dimension *at the time* the setting is done, so in the document preamble. Similarly for `thick`, so the values are set at call time, maybe to be overridden by an explicit option.

[image]

Comment: Why is the `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:` not inside the difinition of `\aze_pencil_diagram:n`? I'd say that two consecutive direct calls of `\aze_pencil_diagram:n` with different arguments shouldn't be able to affect each other.

Comment: @Skillmon No particular reason; I believe that the internal function should not do a group and this is the job of the user interface, that's all.

Comment: Why do you use the notation `aze/pencil`?

Comment: I forgot to say thanks :)

Comment: @azetina `aze` is for “azetina”. The prefix for this code is `aze` and the functions and variables are about `pencil`.